# Accessing variables from .load() page

Tags: php, jquery, variables, load, return

I have my index.php and load lets say "content.php" with .load() into a div on window onload.
How can I use variables from the content.php in my index.php
For instance: 
Let´s say I have a variable called $something in my content.php. And I want to use that variable in my index.php

In my index.php:

```
<head>
$(function Loadcontent() {
    $("#content").load("content.php")
});
window.onLoad = Loadcontent();
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

in my content.php file i now declare a variable:

```
$something = 1;
```

I now want to use $something in index.php

Comment: Showing some code will help to answer.

Comment: You use AJAX for that.

Comment: You can not, index.php has been rendered by the server already.

Comment: I added some pseudo code. quick and dirty.

Comment: can you give me an example eisa adil?

Comment: Is `$something` a PHP variable?  Do you want to use that PHP variable in the index.php page?  If so, this is not how to do it.  When your `Loadcontent()` runs, `index.php` will be done running.  `content.php` will run on its own, and should echo something (to be put in `$("#content")`).  Why not try to `include 'content.php';` in your `index.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Ajax for that, plenty on the web

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp